# Minting dependent on NFT ownership

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, mint

How can I add some additional vaidation to my `mint` function to check if the person minting the nft owns an item from a specific NFT collection.

In other words, I own 2 collections.  I want a user to only be able to mint from collection A in they already own an item in collection B.

```
function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
    require(to != address(0), "ERC721: mint to the zero address");
    require(!_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: token already minted");

    // some additional check here? 
    // psuedocode: _hasItemInCollection(to);

    _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), to, tokenId);

    _balances[to] += 1;
    _owners[tokenId] = to;

    emit Transfer(address(0), to, tokenId);
}
```

**Edited**: I moved this logic to live in the `mint` function, not the internal `_mint` function.  Here is the updated code:

```
function mint(uint256 _mintAmount) public payable mintCompliance(_mintAmount) {
    require(!paused, "The contract is paused!");

    // not A *REAL* contract address, your contract address HERE. 
    address patronAccessToken = 0x000000001234567890ABCDEF0001112022222222;

    bool isPatron = (IToken(patronAccessToken).balanceOf(msg.sender) > 0);
    if (isPatron == true) {
        setCost(0.015 ether);
    }
    require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount, "Insufficient funds!");

    _mintLoop(msg.sender, _mintAmount);
}
```

Thank you for your wisdom!

Comment: So if a user has minted in collection A, will the _balances value of the user in A be >0 ? If it is, that can be used a way to detect if the user has minted in A.

Comment: @pbsh Yes, but I think that I need to check the `_balances` or `_owners` of collection *B*. if we are trying to mint in collection A then `_balances` in this function are correlated with the current collection (user may have zero or more).  I though i'd need to perform a lookup to etherscan or something to check. - sorry I am a newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that both the contracts are created using [this](https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_nft_contract/blob/main/contract/SimpleNft_flat.sol) template based on the code you posted.

Let's say contract A is deployed at `ADDRESS_A`. We'll need to add an interface to interact with contract A.

```
interface IToken {
    function balanceOf(address) external view returns (uint256);
}
```

Now in our `_mint` function, we can check if the `msg.sender` has previously minted in contract A. To do that, we will create an instance of the contract using our interface.

```js
function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
    require(to != address(0), "ERC721: mint to the zero address");
    require(!_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: token already minted");

    require(IToken(ADDRESS_A).balanceOf(msg.sender),"HAVE NOT MINTED A TOKENS")

    _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), to, tokenId);

    _balances[to] += 1;
    _owners[tokenId] = to;

    emit Transfer(address(0), to, tokenId);
}
```

Now the mint function will only proceed if the `msg.sender` balance is non-zero in contract A.

Comment: I will for sure. I am going to test it first. thank you again!

Comment: This is very nice. I don't know why I didn't "get it" that you can reference any other contract from your contract. So you can do interesting, yet ethical or moral questionable things here.

e.g. I can check for Bored Ape or CryptoPunk owners and ban them from minting or even buying my NFT if I wanted using the opposite of this code.

Comment: You sure can. Smart contracts are unstoppable that way, almost all data is public and accessible, thus interactable.

Comment: I was planning to allow owners of my first collection to mint future collections for a lower minting cost.

Comment: @pbsh should I be handling this in the `mint` function or is there a place earlier in the process? can we perform this detection before the `mint` step, so the person minting can *see* the adjusted mint price before they attempt to mint?  thank you for all your help.

Comment: You can implement it in the `mint` function itself. Or you can also create a `getPrice` function and check the price inside it. You can use that inside `mint` and also call externally, to get the discounted price.